# Расчет движения по спирали

Tags: математика, геометрия, интегральное-исчисление

Есть вопрос, нужна ваша "математика".

**Задача**

Простая, известная закономерность: предмет с точки `x1` движется по прямой в точку `x2`, с постоянной скоростью `V`. Пройденное расстояние `S` можно вычислить как `S = x2-x1`. Равно как и затраченное время `T=S/V`, но задача в другом ...

Есть полый цилиндр длинною `L` и радиусом `R`. Точка начинает движение с начала цилиндра (нижняя точка начала цилиндра `L1`) по его внутренней поверхности c начальным углом относительно оси симметрии цилиндра `α1`,`α2` (ибо это уже 3-х мерное измерение). Естественно, траектория движения точки будет представлять собой - **спираль**. Нужна формула вычисления "пройденного пути" по спирали до конечной точки цилиндра. Интересуют - "пройденный путь" и "затраченное время".

**Вангую:** должно появиться что-то интегральное ... но я все забыл напрочь. Помогите, пожалуйста!

ADD: Известно:

R - радиус цилиндра
L - длина цилиндра
V - начальная скорость
А - угол траектории (пусть один)

Надо вычислить: S - пройденный путь по спирали, T - скорость прохождения цилиндра.

Comment: Цилиндр отлично разворачивается в плоскость. Пройденный путь всё так же считается как время умножить на скорость.

Comment: L/sin(α), если я правильно понял, какой угол задан

Comment: Ну и угол всё же один, т.к. это поверхность цилиндра

Answer (score 3):

Надеюсь, вам поможет представить ситуацию вот эта картинка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, спираль легким движением руки превращается в прямую... И никаких интегралов просто не нужно.

Хотя, если хотите — можно и их использовать, но это уже из серии "зачем просто, если можно сложно?"

Ну, а движение по прямой вы уже знаете, судя по началу вопроса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Интересное решение. Но нужно как-то обозначить "скорость спуска" ... А, по факту, количество витков на спуске, и, как следствие - результирующую длину пути.

Comment: @Majestio не нужно. Путь зависит только от высоты цилиндра  и угла. Количество витков зависит от радиуса, но в вашем вопросе оно не нужно.

Comment: Ждем формулы Пути (расстояния по сути) и Скорости Прохождения (не угловой)

Comment: @Majestio так формула вторым комментарием выше написана.

Comment: У вас какие-то странные заказы в условии... T - скорость, V - *начальная* скорость... Точка замедляется? ускоряется? Что такое "нижняя точка начала цилиндра"? Что за *два* угла? Нарисовали бы вы чертеж... А то все так неоднозначно :( Если все так, как понимаю я — угол спирали, L - высота цилиндра, V - *постоянная* скорость движения, то формулу (в 8 классе такие пишут, если не ошибаюсь) я привел.

Comment: Кажется под Т всё-таки понимается *время* прохождения.